# How to read columns which matches certain criteria like '%string%' into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read excel sheet into a dataframe with only certain columns. I can create a list of columnnames I want and pass it in "usecols" in pd.read_excel. But everytime the column name changes slightly so i want a way to read into df only columns that contains specific substring. for example, this month column names are "oknDATAkon" but next month it will be "otDATApy". So I am trying to find a way to read only column names that match '%DATA%' and there will be a list of different columns like this.
Also this might be a long shot but is there anyway I can filter the records in the above columns again matching a particular substring whilst reading into a dataframe? I can do it after the df is created but there will be couple of million records so was thinking if it's quicker to do this whilst reading the excel file into a df. Many thanks.

```
names = ['data', 'month', 'salary']
while x< len(xl.sheet_names):
    df = pd.read_excel(fileloc,sheet_name=xl.sheet_names[x],usecols=names)
#     df concat code
    x=x+1
df
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a lambda function with `usecols`. Here is an example

```py
names = ['data', 'month', 'salary']
for sheet_name in xl.sheet_names: 
    df = pd.read_excel(fileloc, sheet_name = sheet_name, usecols= lambda col: any(name.lower() in col.lower() for name in names) )
    # concat code
df
```

About the second question, I am not aware of a way that doesn't involve first reading all rows and filtering them afterwards.

Comment: Hi @Brener Ramos, thank you for the solution. This almost works. The code rund but i am only getting the first column where colname like '%data%'. It's not reading any other's from the list in the df. the only thing I would like to point out is that for other columns first few records are empty. Not sure if this is effecting the run in anyway

Comment: I updated the code to be case insensitive, maybe that is the issue? When I run it on my part with a dummy excel file it seems to work fine so this is the only thing I can think of that might cause problems.